# IMacros цикл

Tags: циклы, imacros

Собвственно вот такой скрипт...

```
VERSION BUILD=6011206 RECORDER=CR 
SET !TIMEOUT_PAGE 10    
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES   
SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES   
SET !DATASOURCE C:\test_url.csv   
SET !LOOP 1    
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}    
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}    
WAIT SECONDS=5    
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:{{!COL2}}    
WAIT SECONDS=5    
TAB CLOSE    
TAB T=1   
SET !LOOP 2    
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}    
WAIT SECONDS=5   
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:{{!COL2}}    
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать циклом вот этот кусок

```
    SET !LOOP 2
URL GOTO={{!COL1}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=HREF:{{!COL2}}
WAIT SECONDS=5
```

Количество строк всегда разное

Answer (score 1):

```
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 5
```

Нужно установить количество колонок в твоем csv файле. У тебя я вижу их две так что значение будет не 5, а 2. Надеюсь, что помог.